# Como envio los datos de un formulario (symfony) y capturarlos en java (Spring)?

Tags: java, php, symfony2, spring

Buen día.
Tengo una aplicación web hecha con symfony2(php), en la cual tengo un formulario con unos datos, los cuales se los quiero enviar a mi otra aplicación web hecha con spring(java). ¿que tecnología y/o tecnologías debo usar para lograr esta comunicación?.

Nota: En la aplicación que tengo con spring tengo servicios REST, no puedo crear otro servicio para la comunicación, ya que todos esos servicios los tengo protegidos , y si creo uno para lograr la conexión que les menciono quedaría vulnerable la aplicación, ya que tendría que hacer una excepción de protección para dicho servicio. Por lo cual necesito otra manera de lograr esta comunicación.

De antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola, si tienes los servicios rest tienes gran parte del trabajo hecho, ya que desde php puedes conectar a dichos servicios, sobre el formato de los datos yo los enviaría en json que esta bastante extendido y hay muchas herramientas que te facilitaran el trabajo, sin conocer más detalles no se puede decir mucho más. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Consumir los servicios rest desde el servidor con curl (esta [librería](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) facilita el trabajo)
2. Consumir los servicios desde el cliente con [javascript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).